# Text not responsive in mobile mode

Tags: bootstrap-4

I've spent ages designing my new website, testing as I went and all seemed ok. But now I've uploaded it, the text doesn't fit within the divs. Please can someone help rectify it? 
Here's the link to my site www.rockclick.co.uk and all my code:

Comment: Sorry, I can't seem to add all my code. I know we're not supposed to add just links to websites, but it won't let me add all my code for some reason.  Can anyone help?

Comment: getting some error check with `f12`

Comment: I made a copy of your code. You have a lot of errors in the HTML and CSS coding structure. Disabling the Style tag in the head will make your page look a little better. However, there are many things that need to be improved. For example, a list created by ul and li ...

Comment: OK so I've had a bit of progress on this, but I'm still having problems with my portfolio page. I replicated the problem in Codepen here : https://codepen.io/JoTidman/pen/RwPWbgx

Comment: The trouble is on different mobile screen sizes the boxes overlap each other and the text isn't responsive when I view the page on my mobile. On a certain size screen the text is way too big and doesn't fit the boxes.